# Error Uploading Video with FileProvider on Android

Tags: android, facebook, youtube, android-youtube-api, android-fileprovider

My app has a video in the files directory that I am having trouble sharing with other apps.  I am using a FileProvider to get a Uri to share. However, it does not appear to be working for some apps (works with GMail and Google Drive but not with YouTube or Facebook).  Is there something I am missing?

```
mButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick( final View theView ) {
                File theMovie = new File( getActivity().getFilesDir() + File.separator + "Data/test.mp4" );
                Uri theMovieUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile( getActivity(), "com.test.provider_demo", theMovie );
                final Intent theShareIntent = new Intent();
                theShareIntent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
                theShareIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
                theShareIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, theMovieUri );
                theShareIntent.setDataAndType( theMovieUri, URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName( theMovieUri.toString() ) );

                List<ResolveInfo > theResolveInfos = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( theShareIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );
                for( ResolveInfo theResolveInfo : theResolveInfos ){
                    String thePackageName = theResolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    getActivity().grantUriPermission( thePackageName, theMovieUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
                }

                getActivity().startActivity( Intent.createChooser( theShareIntent, "Share me!" ) );
            }
        } );
```

FileProvider element from manifest

```
   <provider
        android:authorities="com.test.provider_demo"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_path" />
    </provider>
```

YouTube Crashes here's the logcat

```
01-23 10:34:46.814  12562-13866/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.google.android.youtube, PID: 12562
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at bif.a(SourceFile:504)
        at bif.a(SourceFile:85)
        at bih.doInBackground(SourceFile:274)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Assuming your `<provider>` element is configured properly, you do not need the loop-through-the-activities stuff. Beyond that, please explain what "it does not appear to be working for some apps " means. What are the specific symptoms? Do those apps log anything of note to LogCat, like a stack trace?

Comment: Symptoms vary but YouTube stops almost immediately with an NPE.  Google+ just never sends the file.  I'll add the youtube stack trace and the <provider> tag in my question.

Comment: The `<provider>` seems fine; you should not need that loop. My guess is that these apps suffer from problems that I have heard of with other Google apps not working with `FileProvider`, in that they assume that all `content` `Uri` values are from `MediaStore` and make incorrect decisions from there. I do not know of a workaround that still uses `FileProvider`, though this is starting to get on my nerves and I'm going to have to figure something out. The only thing I know of that should work reliably would be to copy the file to external storage, which may present its own issues for you.

Comment: Yeah the loop was just to show that they definitely had permission to read the file, I agree it is not necessary.   I was hoping to avoid having to copy my files out of my folder but like you I haven't been able to find a work around.  Thanks for taking look.